# how do i Determine a Cut-Off or Threshold When Working With Fuzzymatcher in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-dataclasses, python-datamodel

Please help on the photo is a screenshot of my output and code as well, how do i use the best_match_score **I NEED TO FILTER BY THE RETURNED "PRECISION SCORE**" THE COLUMN ONLY COMES AFTER THE MERGE (i.e. JUST RETURN EVERYTHING with **'best_match_score'** BELOW -1.06)

```
import fuzzymatcher
import pandas as pd
import os

# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

REDCAP = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Selamola\Desktop\PythonThings\FuzzyMatching\REDCAP Form A v1 and v2 23 Feb 211.csv")
covidSheet = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Selamola\Desktop\PythonThings\FuzzyMatching\Cases missing REC ID 23 Feb 211.csv")

Data_merge = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(covidSheet, REDCAP,
                                          left_on=['Participant Name', 'Particfipant Surname', 'Screening Date',
                                                   'Screening Date', 'Hospital Number', 'Alternative Hospital Number'],
                                          right_on=['Patient Name', 'Patient Surname', 'Date Of Admission',
                                                    'Date Of Sample Collection', 'Hospital Number', 'Hospital Number'])

# Merged_data = pd.merge(REDCAP, covidSheet, how='left',
#                        left_on=['Patient Name', 'Patient Surname'],
#                        right_on=['Participant Name', 'Particfipant Surname'])

# Data_merge.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Selamola\Desktop\PythonThings\FuzzyMatching\DataMacth.csv')

print(Data_merge)
```

[image: Image of WorkSpace]

Comment: If you are just asking how to apply a filter, this is a very googleable answer. The first result for "how to filter in pandas" gives lots of options on the results. If this isn't what you were asking, take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for not Adding bit, this but the 'best_match_score' column is generated buy FuzzyMatcher at run time, the natural Panda indexing has no effect

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. However, it might be helpful to post information about your research. This will help people who are having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very straightforward unless I'm missing something. Be sure to try read the documentation about [slicing data in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

```
mask = Data_merge['best_match_score'] < .1.06
filtered_data = Data_merge[mask]
```

Comment: Sorry for not Adding bit, this but the 'best_match_score' column is generated buy FuzzyMatcher at run time, the traditional Panda indexing has no effect

Comment: I don't understand why that wouldn't work. As long as you ran it in the correct order it should work regardless of the process that generated it. What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: When I filter by any other column that came with either spreadsheet it works fine like date or Name, just not 'best_maych_score' I researched it apparently the problem is with the module(fuzzymatcher) and the creators don't answer that question so I'll try fuzzywuzzy